# Parse xml in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have a dataframe with XML in the second column:

Python - atom_acrs.py:1
[Finished in 1.153s]
19/19

```
  FILE_CREATION_DATE                                          FILE_DATA
0         2017-09-06  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><REPORT ...
1         2017-09-07  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><REPORT ...
2         2017-10-09  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><REPORT ...
3         2017-10-10  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><REPORT ...
4         2017-12-06  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><REPORT ...
```

How do I parse the xml in each row and then output it as a table? So that each tag would have a value for each item in the dataframe?

Thanks

Here is a sample of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<REPORT xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CrashReport.DataLayer.v20170201">
<CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>2020-10-08T06:49:31.813812</CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>-
<AGENCYIDENTIFIER>MILWAUKEE</AGENCYIDENTIFIER>-
<AGENCYNAME>Milwaukee Police Department</AGENCYNAME>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your XML content? Parsing an XML has quite a few possibilities.

Comment: Updated with example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume we have a dataframe similar to your example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FILE_CREATION_DATE': ['2017-09-06'], 'FILE_DATA': ['''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<REPORT xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CrashReport.DataLayer.v20170201">
<CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>2020-10-08T06:49:31.813812</CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>-
<AGENCYIDENTIFIER>MILWAUKEE</AGENCYIDENTIFIER>-
<AGENCYNAME>Milwaukee Police Department</AGENCYNAME></REPORT>''']})

df

FILE_CREATION_DATE  FILE_DATA
0   2017-09-06      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>\n<REPO...
```

let's get the possible values from your XML. We'll just take the first row and assume the rest is identical.

```
import import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(df['FILE_DATA'][0])
# we need to get rid of the XML namespace, therefore the split by }
columns = [c.tag.split('}', 1)[-1] for c in root]

# convert each XML into a dictionary and asssign to the columns
df[columns] = df['FILE_DATA'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({c.tag.split('}', 1)[-1]:c.text for c in ET.fromstring(x)}))
df.drop('FILE_DATA', axis=1, inplace=True) 
df


FILE_CREATION_DATE  CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP          AGENCYIDENTIFIER    AGENCYNAME
0                   2017-09-06 2020-10-08...    MILWAUKEE           Milwaukee Police Department
```

Comment: Wow, I think this worked!!!! I will take a better look tomorrow but for now I am going to upvote!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat similar solution to @Maximilian Peter's, but using lxml, xpath (taking into account namespaces), an additional report from Chicago and `map()`:

```
from lxml import etree
data = [["2017-09-06",'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><REPORT xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CrashReport.DataLayer.v20170201"><CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>2020-10-08T06:49:31.813812</CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>-<AGENCYIDENTIFIER>MILWAULLKEE</AGENCYIDENTIFIER>-<AGENCYNAME>Milwaukee Police Department</AGENCYNAME></REPORT>'],\
        ["2017-09-07", '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><REPORT xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CrashReport.DataLayer.v20170201"><CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>2021-11-08T06:49:31.813812</CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>-<AGENCYIDENTIFIER>CHICAGO</AGENCYIDENTIFIER>-<AGENCYNAME>Chicago Police Department</AGENCYNAME></REPORT>']]
columns = ["FILE_CREATION_DATE","FILE_DATA"]

def xpath_extract(my_str):
    doc = etree.XML(my_str.encode())
    a,b,c = [elem.text for elem in doc.xpath('//*[local-name()="REPORT"]//*')]
    return a,b,c  

police_df['TIME'], police_df['AGENCY_ID'], police_df['AGENCY_NAME'] = \
     zip(*police_df['FILE_DATA'].map(xpath_extract))

police_df.drop('FILE_DATA', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     FILE_CREATION_DATE     TIME           AGENCY_ID       AGENCY_NAME
0   2017-09-06  2020-10-08T06:49:31.813812  MILWAULLKEE    Milwaukee Police Department
1   2017-09-07  2021-11-08T06:49:31.813812  CHICAGO        Chicago Police Department
```